# React-Bootstrap Badge is only white text no matter how I change its property. How to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap, badge

I am new to react. I have React app where I try to render a badge. It shows the text but only white.

I imported react-bootstrap with the following in my index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

in app.js I have

```
import Badge from "react-bootstrap/Badge";
```

Everything is working fine but the text is white.
Here is the Badge

```
<h4>
  <Badge className="text-align-center" variant="secondary">
     Editor
  </Badge>
</h4>
```

Badge and text are not visible as below

[image: Here it is. Badge and text are not visible]
If I select the text I can see there is a white text where the badge should be. I'm building a markdown previewer, everything is working fine both inside the editor and previewer.

[image: If I select the text I can see there is a white text where the badge should be.]

Here is the full code: index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Badge from "react-bootstrap/Badge";
let marked = require("marked");


export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    markdown: placeholder,
  };
}

updateMarkdown(markdown){
  this.setState({markdown });
}

  
  
  render(){

    var inputStyle = {
      width: "500px",
      height: "60vh",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      marginRight: "auto",
      padding: "10px"
    };

    var outputStyle = {
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",
      backgroundColor: "#DCDCDC",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      padding: "10px"
    };



    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row mt-4">
            <div className="col text-center">
            <h1>
              {" "}
              <Badge className="text-align-center" variant="light">
                Markdown Previewer 
              </Badge>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>  

            <div className="row mt-4">
              <div className="col-md-6">
                {" "}
                   <div className="col text-center">
                      <h4>
                        <Badge className="text-align-center" bg="secondary" text="dark">
                          Editor
                        </Badge>
                      </h4>
                   </div>
                <div className="input" style={inputStyle}>
                  <textarea
                    id="editor" 
                    className="input" 
                    style={inputStyle} 
                    value={this.state.markdown} 
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      this.updateMarkdown(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  > 
                    
                  </textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="col-md-6">
                {" "}
                <div className="col text-center">
                  <h4>
                    <Badge className="text-align-center" variant="secondary" id="preview" >
                      Previewer
                    </Badge>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div style={outputStyle}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(this.state.markdown)}}></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

'
const placeholder = '# Welcome to my React Markdown Previewer!'
```

Comment: What do you want to change the ```text``` colour or the ```badge``` colour?

Comment: I want the text color to be black, while the badge is secondary

Comment: I had a similar problem. This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330784/is-there-a-problem-with-my-boostrap-badge-not-applying

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused about your question so I'm trying to answer based on what I've assumed so far.

In react-bootstrap `Badge` there are 2 properties:

1. `bg` for The visual style of the badge
2. `text` for Setting badge text colour

Here you go!

If you just want to change the style of the text then use `text` property and if you want to change the style of your badge then use `bg` property

```
<h4>
  <Badge className="text-align-center" bg="secondary" text="dark">
     Editor
  </Badge>
</h4>
```

I hope I've answered your question but if you still have a query, Checkout this link: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/badge/#badge-props

Comment: Still not working. I've added screenshots to the question. I'm building a markdown previewer, everything is working fine both inside the editor and previewer. Only badge text is white. Hope that clarifies what I am trying to do. Can u have a look at it, please?

Comment: Then this is not the issue of the react-bootstrap ```Badge```. This might be the issue with your custom CSS. Maybe your ```Badge```'s CSS is getting overwrite by Custom CSS (if you are using any). Because in the ScreenShot I can clearly see that even your title ```Markdown Previewer``` is not visible until you select the text

Comment: I don't have custom CSS. The title is also a badge, that's why it is not showing too. What could be the reason?

Comment: I've added full code, can u have a look, please?

Comment: share your package version of react-bootstrap